# What are the main differences between AngularJS and ReactJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, reactjs, client-side

I need to create a web site which will be converted to a mobile application (What I want to build is more suited to be a web site than an application so the building itself should be as a website).

Since I'm more familiar with the desktop and Android native dev world, I got very little knowledge of web client side development. After reading a little I've decided to use these technologies for the client side: HTML5, CSS3, Bootstrap, React.js

The problem is that I've read that Angular is actually a full MVC framework while React has some more specific roles and it's like comparing a car (Angular) to an engine (React). I have already seen comparisons regarding how to do some actions with both technologies like hello world and event handling and stuff like that so I don't need to know how to specific things like what they show in some comparison websites.

So my question is what is the difference between what I can accomplish with Angular compared to React? If I use React, are there going to be things I wouldn't be able to do? When should I use one over the other? If I use React, will I still be able to build a fully operational client side?

I would like to emphasize I don't want a personal opinion. I just want the facts regarding client development and to know what I can and can't do with them.

Comment: Quite a few things...

Comment: I don't need a comparison for each and every function. Just in general terms.. since Angular still got the "full framework" title while React doesn't

Comment: What sort of answer are you expecting? car vs engine is apples to oranges comparison

Comment: @charlietfl Exactly. That's why I want to know sort of things I can do with one that I can't do with the other. If Angular is such a complete framework then there must be several things I'll miss if I use React

Comment: Question is far too broad for SO and you can get answers yourself doing a web search

Comment: This is what *the documentation* is for. React has several videos about the topic too.

Comment: Upvote because I understand the intent behind the question and have been there. There are many comparable questions on SO with many upvotes. However, knowing this place, you're likely to get a lot of smarmy antagonism with such a question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AngularJS is a full framework like you said, which is designed to write single page applications (SPA) using the MVC design.
On the other hand, ReactJS is consider to be for the development of the View only, or in other words, UI components.
In my opinion Angular is rather complex to learn while React is relatively a small library, but React is faster for its virtual DOM (It doesn't manipulate the DOM directly unless needed).
Also react can be used with other libraries for things like routing while angular already have it.
I think you can build the same website using both techologies, even though React is for UI, it still can have logic and big websites are built with it (Instagram and Facebook for example).

Comment: Your answer makes me think that I could work with ReactJS and AngularJS simultaneously. Is that possible? You said that React is for UI elements while Angular is a full framework. I know absolutely nothing about React, but that makes me wonder if I could build angular directives using react to make better web components.

Comment: When saying "React is for the View only", what is handling the model and controller?

Comment: Yes you could combine them, but I'd suggest you to choose one of them as you need to do some workaround to combine the two frameworks. About the model and controller part, I forgot to mention that react is designed for a flux development. It means that instead of two way binding you always have one flow of data from the dispatcher to the child components. Any component can register to and trigger function on events. React doesn't need models and controllers because it's a different approach to developing SPA applications.

Comment: If you were to use React for front-end, I would recommend using a flux framework for the backend, such as Redux. Also to add to your original question, React is a UI library whereas AngularJS is a framework. For small applications, ReactJS works fine out of the box. For larger applications, I would definitely pair it up with Redux or such.

Comment: @YonatanNir For each self contained component in react, you will manage the state within the component itself, while for managing the application state you would use a framework like Redux.

Answer (score 3):

I think the main difference between Angular and React is the fact that Angular is using 2 way data binding, while React is using one way. Maybe this article will make the things clearer for you: https://www.airpair.com/angularjs/posts/angular-vs-react-the-tie-breaker

p.s. I really don't understand why this question is downvoted...

Comment: but still there got to be some things since Angular is a full framework while React is not..

Comment: While Angular is very good at managing and updating the DOM, it can get sluggish. React specializes in extremely fast and frequent updates to elements that are often times very data heavy.

Comment: But maybe Angular will have some abilities that React doesn't? (still, the "full framework" title).