# what is the difference between Angular JS and React JS

Tags: angularjs, reactjs, difference

want to know the difference between Angular JS and React JS.  what are all the key features both of them has.

Can somebody guide me here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the main differences between AngularJS and ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34580375/what-are-the-main-differences-between-angularjs-and-reactjs)

Answer (score 0):

Angular js

- Two way binding
- Uses observables to track changes
- Contains many things internally just by installing angular that can be used Like http calls etc

React js

- It has unidirectional flow
- Uses virtual DOM concept.
- For react we have to search for modules (still its easy to. We have lots and lots of modules already available)

Syntax aswell is different. :)

Comment: Working on mobile. Bad formatting. Sorry about it

Comment: Working or Answering?

Comment: Hmm.. Working and answering